# Finding significant factors in a Latin Hypercube Design

Tags: r, anova, latin-hypercube

I'm simulating data where I have four factors and one response that I want to examine. I have two different DoE designs, one 2⁴ factorial design and one Latin Hypercube Design. The ultimate goal with the research is to see if I can see any difference between the two models, i.e. do they give different significant factors for my response depending on the DoE model used.

I understand how to plot and analyze the results from the factorial designs by aggregating the results and then performing ANOVA tests or fitting linear models by:

```
doe.model <- lm(response ~ A + B + C + A * B + A * C + B * C + A * B * C, data = ss.data.doe1)

summary(doe.model)
```

However, I cannot seem to find any way of performing a similar test on my Latin Hypercube design, the 4 factors are assumed continuous and the design is 16 runs, i.e. every simulation has different values for the parameters.  Is there any way of performing a similar analysis for my LHC design? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you could create a similar design using a Latin hypercube in R

```r
#  Assume each parameter or factor covers some continuous range with some distribution
#    A ~ unif(0, 20)
#    B ~ norm(5, 1)
#    C ~ lnorm(1, 1)
#    D ~ exp(2)

# 2^4 factorial design
dataf <- expand.grid(A = c(0, 20),
                     B = c(3, 7),
                     C = c(0, 0.13),
                     D = c(0, 1))

# create a response function
dataf$Y <- with(dataf, 2 + 1.5*A + 1*B + 10*C + 3*D + rnorm(nrow(dataf), 2))

# build the model with all one-way, all two-way, and some three-way interactions
doe.model <- lm(Y ~ (A + B + C + D)^2 + A*B*C + A*C*D, data = dataf)

summary(doe.model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Y ~ (A + B + C + D)^2 + A * B * C + A * C * D, data = dataf)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#>  0.24862  0.06856 -0.24862 -0.06856 -0.29269 -0.02448  0.29269  0.02448 
#>        9       10       11       12       13       14       15       16 
#> -0.24862 -0.06856  0.24862  0.06856  0.29269  0.02448 -0.29269 -0.02448 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  3.438726   0.706903   4.864  0.01659 *  
#> A            1.509233   0.045833  32.929 6.16e-05 ***
#> B            1.087473   0.126152   8.620  0.00328 ** 
#> C           23.426811   7.051292   3.322  0.04498 *  
#> D            3.221236   0.722490   4.459  0.02101 *  
#> A:B         -0.004900   0.007979  -0.614  0.58257    
#> A:C         -0.236171   0.498602  -0.474  0.66808    
#> A:D          0.026490   0.031914   0.830  0.46741    
#> B:C         -2.080207   1.227472  -1.695  0.18870    
#> B:D         -0.190358   0.112834  -1.687  0.19018    
#> C:D          1.867989   4.909889   0.380  0.72895    
#> A:B:C        0.104881   0.086795   1.208  0.31347    
#> A:C:D       -0.280388   0.347182  -0.808  0.47841    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.4513 on 3 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9998, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9992 
#> F-statistic:  1525 on 12 and 3 DF,  p-value: 2.46e-05

# Latin Hypercube Design

require(lhs)
#> Loading required package: lhs
#> Warning: package 'lhs' was built under R version 4.1.3

set.seed(190383)
# select the same number of points in the LHS as are in the factorial design
lhs1 <- lhs::randomLHS(2^4, k = 4)

lhs1 <- as.data.frame(lhs1)
names(lhs1) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

lhs1$A <- qunif(lhs1$A, 0, 20)
lhs1$B <- qnorm(lhs1$B, 5, 1)
lhs1$C <- qlnorm(lhs1$C, 1, 1)
lhs1$D <- qexp(lhs1$D, 2)

lhs1$Y <- with(lhs1, 2 + 1.5*A + 1*B + 10*C + 3*D + rnorm(nrow(lhs1), 2))

lhs.model <- lm(Y ~ (A + B + C + D)^2 + A*B*C + A*C*D, data = lhs1)

summary(lhs.model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Y ~ (A + B + C + D)^2 + A * B * C + A * C * D, data = lhs1)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#>  0.28229  0.08898 -0.82246  0.08808  0.15481 -0.21934 -0.10925  0.38288 
#>        9       10       11       12       13       14       15       16 
#>  0.33827 -0.70871  0.14906 -0.42464 -0.27482  0.38189  0.44519  0.24776 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#> (Intercept)  6.92866   13.29290   0.521   0.6382  
#> A            0.92121    1.17079   0.787   0.4888  
#> B            0.49425    2.69352   0.183   0.8661  
#> C           10.13896    3.47114   2.921   0.0614 .
#> D            2.03010    7.25859   0.280   0.7979  
#> A:B          0.07305    0.19649   0.372   0.7348  
#> A:C          0.12173    0.29728   0.409   0.7097  
#> A:D         -0.30140    0.60378  -0.499   0.6520  
#> B:C          0.02521    0.78468   0.032   0.9764  
#> B:D          1.32527    2.55502   0.519   0.6398  
#> C:D         -3.05593    3.79029  -0.806   0.4791  
#> A:B:C       -0.02192    0.05839  -0.375   0.7324  
#> A:C:D        0.19428    0.24916   0.780   0.4924  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.8761 on 3 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9999, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9996 
#> F-statistic:  2877 on 12 and 3 DF,  p-value: 9.499e-06
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>